# Html5 date regexp даты

Tags: регулярные-выражения, html5, дата

Пытаюсь переделать регулярное выражение даты с http://html5pattern.com/Dates

> (?:19|20)[0-9]{2}-(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31))

под формат 31.01.2017

```
(?:(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31)).(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])).(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}
```

30 и 31 день оно не принимает, как исправить?

Comment: Переписать.. Наверное...

Comment: @Qwertiy
это и пытаюсь. проблема в том, что число проверяется по месяцу и поменяв местами что-то испортилось...

Comment: Ну так надо многое превращать в предпросмотр, наверное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так наверное?

```js
var regex = /(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])|(?:(?:30)-(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]))|(?:31-(?:0[13578]|1[02])))-(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}/;

var dates = ["31-13-2017", "31-12-2017", "32-12-2017", "01-11-2017"];

for(var index in dates) {
 console.log("test " + dates[index] + ": " + regex.test(dates[index]));
}
```

Comment: СпасиБо! Работает (только на точки заменил).